# Getting FreeeMarker exceptions in server logs even though Struts2 f/w being used for a web application

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker, socketexception

I am faced with a mysterious issue which is causing a havoc on availability of my web application. Some background -

- Server - Apache+Tomcat7
- Web Framework - Struts2 with JSPs

On checking the server logs off late I have been getting a lot of following exceptions -

```
26092219 [http-bio-8080-exec-695] ERROR org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine  - Could not load the FreeMarker template named 'hidden':
26092219 [http-bio-8080-exec-695] ERROR org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine  - Attempted: /template/simple/hidden.ftl
26092219 [http-bio-8080-exec-695] ERROR org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine  - The TemplateLoader provided by the FreeMarker Configuration was a: freemarker.cache.MultiTemplateLoader

Error reading included file template/simple/dynamic-attributes.ftl
The problematic instruction:

----------
==> include "/${parameters.templateDir}/simple/dynamic-attributes.ftl" [on line 44, column 1 in template/simple/a-close.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Error reading included file template/simple/dynamic-attributes.ftl
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Error reading included file template/simple/dynamic-attributes.ftl
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:167)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:209)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:189)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:157)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Anchor.end(Anchor.java:145)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp_005froot.ajax.synset.trackedCustomEntities_jsp._jspx_meth_gs_005fa_005f0(trackedCustomEntities_jsp.java:648)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp_005froot.ajax.synset.trackedCustomEntities_jsp._jspx_meth_gs_005fif_005f2(trackedCustomEntities_jsp.java:573)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp_005froot.ajax.synset.trackedCustomEntities_jsp._jspx_meth_gs_005fiterator_005f0(trackedCustomEntities_jsp.java:380)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp_005froot.ajax.synset.trackedCustomEntities_jsp._jspService(trackedCustomEntities_jsp.java:128)
...
```

This keeps on happening which then leads to - `too many open files` exception like so,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/_/loader/template/simple/form.ftl (Too many open files)
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    ...
```

I am confused mainly because I do not have one single freemarker file in the codebase. My guess is this is happening from inside some library I have imported and the trouble being that I have tons of library so going through each one of them & figuring out which one is behaving will be not feasible.

The temp. hack I have in place is to just restart the server & double the "ulimit -n" size. But this is just a bandaid. I would like to get to the bottom of this issue & resolve it either by removing the offending library or by including the missing library!?!?.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**
The dump of stacktraces I collected over a period of few hours - https://gist.github.com/4e22ffd19f0445521083 Hopefully this gives some pointers.

Comment: What's the cause exception of that `TemplateException`? Isn't that also a "too many open files"? Because then maybe the problem is that sometimes a template falls out of the template cache, then suddenly a lot of threads (i.e., visitors) need it, so it's opened and parsed in parallel until it's in the cache again. Could that deplete the max file handles?

Comment: There's no missing library; S2 uses FreeMarker for its custom tags. As to why it's happening, not sure--never seen this before. Are you doing something in your app with custom themes, or serving static files, or...?

Comment: @ddekany I think something is causing too many open files to happen & my guess that it is due to this file not found exceptions.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am defintely serving static files. But I dont know about custom themes. Actually I have inherited the codebase so I dont know all the ins & outs of it, so I am at a loss myself. You say static files, how should I debug that?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException`-s occur when the OS is out of file handles, if I understand it well, not the other way around. Again, maybe it would be helpful to see the cause exception of that `TemplateException`, because that's maybe also  a `FileNotFoundException` due too many open files.

Comment: @ddekany Here is the dump of stacktraces I collected over a period of few hours - https://gist.github.com/4e22ffd19f0445521083 Hopefully this gives some pointers. Thanks!